# Speeding up VS2010 "SharePoint" cycle times for Web Part development

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, web-parts, cycle

I am starting work on a SharePoint 2010 Project and using the Visual Studio 2010 Built-In Magical Extension to do so. However, the turn-about cycle to *re-deploy* the solution is terribly long (build, package, retract, deploy, then restart, etc.) The only changes during this time have been to the individual Web Parts.

In the past I have used WSP Builder and for minor updates *on the dev box* just using the Copy-to-GAC/Copy-to-Hive features which has a *much shorter turn-about* to see changes to a Web Part. I was wondering if there was a similar (or alternative) method to get a similar quick turn-about in VS2010? The Mapped Folders address say, a changing view, but it's the Web Parts that interest me most now.

Please, if you are going to say "but you should always re-deploy", please do so only as a suggestion with other [useful] advice -- the testing servers get a full re-deploy. This is simply about helping me reduce the development cycle times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Copy to 14 / Copy to GAC functionality in Visual Studio 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/4726/950)

Comment: Thanks for the link (and tip-off to sharepointoverflow). I'm using CKS now and the quick-deploy from the context-menu works (but no hotkey? :-/), but the deploy from the Deployment settings determines the wrong local path and fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy the BIN directory rather than the GAC then you can just do a copy on postbuild - no restart/deploy etc needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- Separated BIN and GAC now (and shut down all "extra" SharePoint services/features/timers) -- works *much* quicker.